# How can I use two test methods in single Test Class for JavaFx UI testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx, junit, testfx

I am currently facing an exception while loading the UI controller.

Have written two separate methods for testing client requests for a server while loading files.

I have start methods which loads UI controller-

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
```

and test methods are as follows:

1. First test

   ```java
   @Test
   @DisplayName("load the files")
   public void testRoutineA() throws URISyntaxException, NullPointerException, IOException {
   ```
2. Second test

   ```java
   @Test
   public static void testRoutineB() throws IOException {
   ```

Issue:

- testRoutineA runs fine and load the UI.
- But when testRoutineB runs it again call the Sart method and throws exception:

Exception in Async Thread ---
Failed to load FXML files.

Any suggestion how to use both methods ?

Comment: Is there more to the error? How are you starting and stopping the JavaFX platform? Are you using _TestFX_? Instead of providing code snippets, can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I am using import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationTest;

Comment: Error:

--- Exception in Async Thread ---
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/..../build/resources/main/com/../../UI/ImageUI.fxml

 javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. Comments are hard to read and cannot be formatted as elegantly.

Comment: This is Start method:
 public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        PlatformImpl.setImplicitExit(false);
        URL fxmlResource = this.getClass().getResource("../UI/ImageUI.fxml");
        if (fxmlResource != null) {
            final var loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlResource);
            final var mainApp = (Pane) loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(mainApp, 1200, 1000));
            stage.show();
            stage.toFront();
        } else {        
        }
    }

Comment: "Please [edit] your question to add more information. Comments are hard to read and cannot be formatted as elegantly."—@Slaw